# Правильное употребление глагола со словом "услуга"

Tags: лексика

Услуги оказываются и услуги предоставляются. Оба варианта имеют право на существование? И в чем разница?

Answer (score 4):

Выражение "**предоставление** услуги" носит формальный, часто коммерческий характер. При этом предоставление услуги может заранее предлагаться. Услуга может быть "**оказана**" другу или знакомому (чаще всего по просьбе) - в таких случаях о "предоставлении" услуги не говорят.